# PGError:Error: must be owner of relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have using rails application with PostgreSql database.
My application is working fine with PostgreSql. 
I want to run my migration on server, I run a command RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
then I get following error:

> PGError:Error: must be owner of
>   relation table_name

I don't understand why this error occurs?
Please suggest any solution to resolve this error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to change something in the table, but you don't have the permissions to do so. Only the owner of the table can do so.

Use a different database role, the owners role, and you're fine.

Comment: How do you change the role?

Comment: ALTER TABLE foo OWNER TO bar; to change ownership.
To change role, make sure you are granted it or use a superuser role.  You can log in as postgres or another superuser (probably easiest without getting into the role system).